# How to find how much height of an element is visible in viewport and accordingly place buttons in the center of the visible area?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to put 2 buttons in the centre of a vertically long div. Which should render the arrow buttons based on the the amount of div visible in the viewport. Please help.

So I wrote this use Effect with scroll event listeners, which should've generated the div's top style as a state (here [arrowPosition, setArrowPosition]). But my visibleHeight value isn't right. As I scroll from top it works fine and then goes back where it should have stayed.
The div has lazy loading inside of it so the div might expand so I thought it would be necessary to use a logic for this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
        const { top, bottom, height } = epgRowsSpanRef.current.getBoundingClientRect(),
            windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
            topIntersection = Math.max(0, top),
            bottomIntersection = Math.max(0, windowHeight - bottom),
            visibleHeight = Math.min(height, Math.max(0, windowHeight - topIntersection - bottomIntersection)),
            visiblePercent = Math.round((visibleHeight / height) * 100);

        setArrowPosition(`${visiblePercent / 2}%`);
        console.log('show arrow', visibleHeight);
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, [epgRowsSpanRef]);
```

Comment: you can get the viewport's height, the height of an element, and its scroll position. Out from that you can calculate how much of the element is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use intersection observer for this. Checkout MDN example here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

```
function buildThresholdList() {
  let thresholds = [];
  let numSteps = 20;

  for (let i = 1.0; i <= numSteps; i++) {
    let ratio = i / numSteps;
    thresholds.push(ratio);
  }

  thresholds.push(0);
  return thresholds;
}

function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const ratio = entry.intersectionRatio;
    // calculate % visible from this
  });
}



function createObserver() {
  let observer;

  let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: buildThresholdList(),
  };

  observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
  observer.observe(boxElement);
}
```

Comment: Approach is good. If time permits, complete the code for others to understand it better,

Comment: An example is given in the link I have added in answer.